# d3.js bar chart animations

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on this bar chart application.

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/166/

How do I

a) animate the bars so they grow from the bottom
b) morph the axis accordingly to the new data set

```
animateBars: function(data){

                        var svg = d3.select(methods.el["selector"] + " .barchart");
                        var barrects = d3.select(methods.el["selector"] + " .barrects");


                        var initialHeight = 0;      



                        var bar = barrects.selectAll("rect")
                            .data(data);

                        // Enter
                        bar.enter()
                            .append("rect")
                            .attr("class", "bar")
                            .attr("y", initialHeight);

                        // Update
                        bar
                            .attr("height", initialHeight)
                            .transition()
                            .duration(500)
                            .attr("x", function(d) { return methods.x(d.letter); })
                            .attr("width", methods.x.rangeBand())
                            .attr("y", function(d) { return methods.y(d.frequency); })
                            .attr("height", function(d) { return methods.height - methods.y(d.frequency); })

                        // Exit
                        bar.exit()
                            .transition()
                            .duration(250)
                            .attr("y", initialHeight)
                            .attr("height", initialHeight)
                            .remove();



                    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the former, set the `y` attribute to be the max height instead of 0:

```
.attr("y", methods.height)
```

For the latter, recompute the `x` domain and call the axis component again:

```
methods.x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
svg.select("g.x").call(methods.xAxis);
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/168/).

Comment: Thank you Lars - I've improved the fiddle to also alter the y axis - and to take on multiple charts. http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/171/

Comment: Lars - I got a stacked chart - that has similar problems - I've tried adapting it to the code on the bar chart - but its not animating as planned. http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/172/

Comment: That one doesn't work for me at all -- might be better to have a separate question about it.

Comment: Lars -  I've made a stacked chart - based on the bar chart one. But if I enable the other charts - take out the comments in the html -it produces the various stacked charts at various widths/heights but does not update/produce any stacks - jsfiddle.net/XnngU/4